# Is there an eslint rule to check if the list has more than 0 items

Tags: typescript, eslint

So, I love typescript a lot, but I get a lot of stupid errors because I use lists with 0 items. Is there an eslint rule to put a red line under the `list[0]` with the saying: 'List might be 0 items'

Comment: Don't you just want [the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the purpose of eslint. I'd recommend to simply check how many items there are in the array and using [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) (which will give you errors when compiling and having no checks):

```
if (items.length > 0) {
 // do stuff
}
```